# excel partial match in reverse

Tags: excel, string-matching

I have two columns. One has values like:

```
0008347_abcd
2008756_abgr
0008746_gss1
.......
```

and a second column with 4 digit numbers that some of the above column entries will partially match i.e.

```
8347
8746
...
```

I want to find which of the first column entries have a partially matching entry in the second column. It can return anything (true false, 0 1), i just want to find them. so in the above example it would flag the first and third values. Moreover there might be multiple entries in column 1 that match one entry in column 2 and I would like to flag them all.

The first column has 3346 entries and the second 334. Can you help me do this in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you 1s and 0s:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$2,A1))))
```

[image]

---

For TRUE/FALSE:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$2,A1))))>0
```

Comment: @John_Mout please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.